# Make Sublime Text 3 the default editor for Python Files. MAC OSX: El Capitan OS

Tags: python, macos, sublimetext3, default

How do I make sublime text the default text editor for python and other code files.

I've tried using open with and changing the default application, but that does not solve the issue.

[Here is my attempt at solving the issue]

Comment: [Here is my attempt at solving your issue.]

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Open the file's "Get Info" pane. (Right click on the file, select "Get Info")

Once this pane is open, under "Open with:", select Sublime Text, and **make sure to select "Change All.." below this option.**

[image]

Comment: not working for xcode vs sublime text for .php files

Comment: I can confirm this approach still works as of today - on High Sierrra OSX , thank you!

Comment: Works with mojave as well

Comment: That exactly not working if XCode is installed, because of the security issue :/